# Merging mp4 files (in order) using ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg, mp4

I am trying to merge two mp4 files (both with video and audio) using ffmpeg, and while I can get them to merge perfectly fine, the order that I need the videos to be in is incorrect. I have gotten other mp4 files to merge in the correct order with no issues, but I cannot seem to get this one to do the same.

Comment: what's the command you're using?

Answer (score 0):

If it were me I would utilize FFmpeg's concat function.

First create a txt file containing the file paths to your aforementioned mp4 files:

```
file 'C:\Users\[username]\Videos\File1.mp4'
file 'C:\Users\[username]\Videos\File2.mp4'
```

Then call back to that file using this command:

```
ffmpeg -f concat -safe 0 -i "C:\Users\[username]\Documents\Concatenate.txt" -c:v copy -c:a copy File1+2.mp4
```

In this example I named the txt file "Concatenate.txt" but you can name it whatever you want. The result should be a file containing both video files one after another in the order you listed them in the txt file.

Comment: can you help me to find the command to set an image as the background for mp4 file using ffmpeg